# How to show sub-menu content with lower fonts?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this website: http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/

On the menu we have "Partners". When we hove over "Partners", then we need to show each partner in one line, maybe with smaller fonts.

The html code is:

```html
 <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-836" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-836"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/university-of-cyprus/">University of Cyprus</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-942" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-942"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/state-health-services-organisation-shso/">State Health Services Organisation (SHSO)</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-831" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-831"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/cyta/">Cyprus Telecommunications Authority (CYTA)</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-816"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/3aehealth-ltd/">3AeHealth LTD</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-826" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-826"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/ubitech-ltd/">UBITECH LTD</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-808" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-808"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/international-institute-for-compassionate-care/">International Institute for Compassionate Care</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-811" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-811"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/hippocrateon-private-hospital/">HIPPOCRATEON Private Hospital</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-941" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-941"><a href="http://ehealth4u.cs.ucy.ac.cy/index.php/partners/iron-mountain-cyprus-ltd/">Iron Mountain Cyprus LTD</a></li>
    </ul>
```

We tried the following without any luck:

```
ul.sub-menu li a{
    font-size:4px;
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this way

```
#menu-custom-menu li ul li a {
    font-size: 4px;
}
```

Expand width

```
.main-navigation ul li ul{
   width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there a way to expand the width of the sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

That rule it is not applied because you have set a selector with an higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) at line 66 of the source code

```
#menu-custom-menu a {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

so either you reduce the specificity of this selector or you increase the specificity of the submenu selector

```
#menu-custom-menu ul.sub-menu li a{
    font-size:4px;
}
```

If you also need to have a larger submenu change the `width` defined from line `509` of the style.css file

Answer (score 0):

You have a style

```
#menu-custom-menu a {
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

It doesn't let your style work.

Try to write with !important property. Something like that:

```
#menu-custom-menu li ul li a {
    font-size: 4px !important;
}
```